# The real line can be embedded in non compact manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a non-compact manifold. Then $\exists$ an embedding $f:\mathbb{R}\to M$.

My attempt: I am trying to show that there is a complete smooth nonvanishing vector field on the manifold $M$ whose integral curve is not a closed curve. I took compact exhaustion and tried defining a vector field, but I seem to run into trouble.

EDIT: Embedding means: Injective immersion which is a proper map.

Comment: Why not just use any coordinate system, which is a diffeomorphism of an open subset with $\mathbb R^n$? By the way, you should probably assume $M$ has positive dimension, otherwise the statement isn't true.

Comment: There should always be a smooth embedding from $\mathbb{R}$ to any (positive-dimension) manifold $M$, compact or not. Just embed in a small open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and use a manifold chart to pull the embedding back to $M$.

Comment: Following the above ideas: $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic (even diffeomorphic) to $(0,1)$. Show that there is always an open intervall $(0,1)$ in a manifold (for example, use a coordinate system).

Comment: @Didier  But That might not give the map to be proper. In particular take $S^1$. Then $ S^1\setminus \{N\}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ but it is not an embedding because the inverse of $S^1$ is whole $R$ which is not compact. In general we need to take a chart whose closure is non-compact, otherwise the preimage of the compct closure, is whole real line which is not compact.

Comment: It sounds like you omitted a hypothesis of "proper" in your post. Perhaps you should think carefully about all the hypotheses you want to be satisfied, and edit your post to include them all explicitly.

Comment: As it stands, "embedding" appears to mean a topological embedding, i.e. a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ onto a subspace of $M$, which is what all the commenters (including myself) took it to mean.

Comment: @Didier $\mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $ (0,1)\times \{0\}$ but is not an embedding.

Comment: @epsilon_delta Your definition of embeding is not standard, as pointed out Lee Mosher.

Comment: This is the definition is from the book by John M. Le's Intr. to smooth manifolds. I don't know any other definition.

Comment: It seems that Lee these "proper embeddings"

Comment: @AlexK is it possible to solve the problem in the latest form? Intuitively, it is clear that such an embedding exists but it is hard to write one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only proof I can think of for this ends up having a lot of moving parts, but here's a rough sketch:

- Choose an exhaustion of $M$ by compact submanifolds with boundary $C_0\subset C_1\subset C_2,\cdots\subset M$ (such an exhaustion can be constructed from a Morse exhaustion function).
- Let $A_i=C_i\setminus\operatorname{int}(C_{i-1})$, and let $A_{i,1}\cdots,A_{i,N_i}$ be the connected components of $A_i$. (This effectively partitions $M$ into compact, connected submanifolds glued together along their common boundaries.)
- Consider $A_{i_1,j_1}$ and $A_{i_2,j_2}$ to be adjacent if they share a boundary component. This allows one to consider the $A_{i,j}$ to be the vertices of a graph.
- Show this graph is infinite and connected, and that all vertices have finite degree, implying it contains a ray $A_{i_0,j_0},A_{i_1,j_1},A_{i_2,j_2},\cdots$.
- Choose and $x_0\in\operatorname{int}(A_{i_0,j_0})$ and $x_k\in\partial A_{i_{k-1},j_{k-1}}\cap\partial A_{i_k,j_k}$.
- Construct embedded paths $\gamma_k:[0,1]\to A_{i_k,j_k}$ with $\gamma_k(0)=x_k$, $\gamma_k(1)=x_{k+1}$, and $\gamma_k((0,1))\subset\operatorname{int}(A_{i_k,j_k})$, chosen so that $\gamma_k$ and $\gamma_{k+1}$ can be smoothly concatenated.
- Show the path $\gamma:\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}\to M$ defined by $\gamma(t)=\gamma_k(t-k)$ for $k\le t< k+1$ is a proper embedding of the ray $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$.
- Construct a properly embedded  closed tubular neighborhood around $\gamma$.
- Properly embed $\mathbb{R}$ in this neighborhood.